# как приклеить sound Swift2.0

Tags: ios, swift

имеется clock

`time = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "upTimeLabel", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

```
}  // скобка закрытия viewDidLoad = ?

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    upTimeLabel()
}

func upTimeLabel() {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    // formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle   //старое выражение...

    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

    timeShow.text = formatter.stringFromDate(clock.currentTime)

    var soundClock = formatter.dateFormat

     switch soundClock {

     case "18 53 00" : let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("k_k0001", ofType: "mp3")!


    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        self.soundClock = sound

        // soundClock.numberOfLoops = -1

        sound.play()
    } catch {
        // couldn't load file :(
        }  //  скобка закрытия плеера = do...

     default : let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("soundAvtomat", ofType: "mp3")!

     let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

     do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        self.soundClock = sound

        // soundClock.numberOfLoops = -1

        sound.play()
     } catch {
        // couldn't load file :(
        }  //  скобка закрытия плеера  // ) скобка закрытия case...

    }  //скобка switch
```

и так далее... нужно на каждый час встроить свой саунд... по дефаулту все отрабатывает, (значит живет...) но case в символьном не 
схватывает (ОШ нет) - пробовал в символке менять формат - запятые и : 
но никак...
если подставить в Int = ОШ

Comment: вы можете нормально написать то вам надо сделать и что не получается? что такое приклеить sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш кейс с пробелами

```
 case "18 53 00"
```

При этом, Вы передаете  в switch `soundClock`, который `var soundClock = formatter.dateFormat`, а это всего-навсего `"HH:mm:ss"`.

Во-первых, передавайте отформатированное время, а не `formatter`. Во-вторых, правильный `case` сделайте.

Comment: вопрос решился за счет = var soundClock: String! = timeShow.text и case = "18:53:00" - все зачирикало....спасибо...

Comment: не долго птичка танцевала...sound звучит ровно столько сколько допускает таймер...(1сек) потом все, включая case ,перезапускается...если выбросить switch за пределы работы таймера ,то требуется declaration...пробовал разные варианты от AVAudioPlayer(duration, timeInterval...) = 0 , подставил на case : func kk0012() ,(вместо всего,что там было ранее) которую вынес за пределы часов...запускается звук так же как и ранее = 1 сек и больше не хочет...все равно длительность сбрасывается от case = ? мысли кончились... @VAndrJ